# Custom client-side ASP.NET MVC 3 Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I'd like to change the default behavior of the client-side validation that ASP.NET MVC 3 uses in this way:

If there is an error,  I don't want any span added to the HTML to show me my mistake.
The only thing I want is to change the color of the input field which has the error.

I don't know if this is the "right" way to do it but this is what I already did:

I edited the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js:

```
  function onError( error, inputElement )
  {  // 'this' is the form element
        var container = $( this ).find( "[data-valmsg-for='" + inputElement[0].name + "']" ),
        replace = $.parseJSON( container.attr( "data-valmsg-replace" ) ) !== false;

  container.removeClass( "field-validation-valid" ).addClass( "field-validation-error" );

  inputElement.addClass( "custom-validation-error" ); // <--------- this is my edit
  error.data( "unobtrusiveContainer", container );

  if( replace )
  {
     container.empty();
     error.removeClass( "input-validation-error" ).appendTo( container );
  }
  else
  {
     error.hide();
  }
 }
```

This only adds the class named custom-validation-error which changes the color of the input field.
But, how do I remove this class, if everything is ok?

And how do I stop from adding the spans to my HTML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the answer was REALLY simple..

I just added this CSS rule:

```
.custom-validation-error  
{
   border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

removed my javascript code and removed the Html.ValidationMessageFor as Darin Dimitrov suggested.

Damn, damn...

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `Html.ValidationMessageFor` field which is responsible for adding the `<span>` tag in which the error message will be shown. So all you need is a `Html.EditorFor`. Then get rid of the javascript you have written.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the Html.ValidationMessageFor, but I don't want to remove my javascript because I won't have the red border that I want. The red color is added to my non-valid input fields, my problem is that I cannot remove them when my input is valid!

Comment: But you don't need any javascript. When a field is invalid ASP.NET MVC automatically adds the `custom-validation-error` class to it. So all you have to do is to write the corresponding CSS rule and put a red border around it.